# Calling function with string argument containing strings

Tags: org-mode

I'm trying to call a function with an argument string, where the string should contain a string inside:

`(org-ql-sparse-tree "(tags \"week4\")")`

If I just do `M-:` and type `(org-ql-sparse-tree "true")<RET>`, then that returns several results. If I type `M-x`, `org-ql-sparse-tree<RET>` and `(tags "week4")<RET>`, then that also returns results. But when I do `(org-ql-sparse-tree "(tags \"week4\")")` either from another function or from `M-:`, it prints `0 matches`.

I suspect this is just a problem escaping the double quotes or something like that. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This has nothing to do with string syntax. The function you are talking about doesn’t take a string, it takes an sexp. You should edit your question so that it refers only to `org-query-ql-sparse-tree` with out assuming that you have to do something weird to call a function that takes a string.

Comment: Use `\\"`, not `\"`. In Lisp strings you need to double backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

`org-ql-sparse-tree` and the other query functions from this package take queries in the form of s–expressions, which will show up in your code as quoted lists. Like this:

```lisp
(org-ql-sparse-tree '(tags "week4"))
```

There is an alternate query syntax that is embedded in a string, if you prefer. The same query would look like this:

```lisp
(org-ql-sparse-tree "tags:week4")
```

Consult the package documentation for more details, specifically the [non–sexp query syntax](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-ql/tree/master#non-sexp-query-syntax) section which has a table showing equivalent forms in both syntaxes.

Comment: The first way works, the second doesn't.

Comment: Then consult the documentation, or ask the package author. Either way, please revise the question since it has nothing to do with how you put double–quote characters into strings.